# Proof that $A^{-1}=adj(A)/|A|$

Tags: matrices, inverse

I know that inverse of a matrix is given by $adj(A)/|A|$ but I cannot prove it.Nor did I find the proof in my books.Can you guide me?

Comment: This is essentially [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

Comment: Did you actually try writing out the transpose of the cofactor matrix and multiplying by $A$?

Comment: Did it for 2*2 and 3*3 and it works! :-D!Wanted to generalize it...that's all ! @A.P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate the product  $A\cdot\text {adj}(A)$ (actually you need the transpose, but I assume you included it in your definition of adj), each entry is of the form "sum of elements of  a row of $A $ times cofactors". For those elements not in the diagonal of  $A $, these correspond to the determinant of a matrix with two repeated rows, so they are zero. The diagonal elements are precisely $|A|$.

Comment: But I mean how was it discovered?It's really strange for someone to think of it for the first time...cofactors and all....anyway +1 for your answer!

Comment: I don't know the actual history, but things like this are usually a combination of the ideas of several very smart people working first on examples and abstracting from there. I

Comment: @SanchayanDutta As you do more and more of your own mathematics, this sort of thing bothers you less and less. When working on a difficult problem, very often the solution will just pop into your head after a long time thinking about it, seemingly out of the blue. Other times you find a solution in a more natural way, but then a radical and more elegant reformulation of it comes into your head out of nowhere. If that can happen to you, just imagine the kinds of crazy ideas that would appear when the best minds in history spend their lives working on problems over thousands of years.